# How to install apt-get if there is no

Tags: meego

I've bought a new netbook with MeeGo preinstalled. Surprisingly I didn't find any apt-get there.

```
sudo apt-get: command not found
```

I need to install apt-get somehow 0_o

Comment: meego != ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meego uses the RPM Package Manager (like Fedora does) instead of dpkg that Ubuntu uses.
So to install software :

```
yum install yourPackage
```

Comment: please answer me shortly: 1)is MeeGo a Fedora? 2)That means I can't use sudo. How to use root? 3)Can I use soft for Debian? 4)What are the major differences between Fedora and Debian?

Comment: sorry, I was in panic ))). It looks like MeeGo is Debian and uses sudo and all other stuff. Still I can't run `sudo yum install apt-get`

Comment: Meego is not a Fedora spin (but Fedora made a spin based on Meego). You can use sudo. You would need to recompile Debian software (most popular software have a .rpm download). You'll need to read on internet for the differences between fedora and Debian (The biggest difference probably is the package systems)

Comment: Meego is not Debian based but has a Linux Kernel so yes sudo works. And no you can't install apt-get (it can't use .deb)

Comment: You should ask your questions here : http://forum.meego.com/

Answer (score 1):

On Meego you can use zypper or yum:

```
 yum install example
```

Or

```
 zypper install example
```

Comment: what are the differences between yum and zypper?

Comment: `sudo yum install apt-get` shows there is no package apt-get

Comment: I was trying to say that you should use this instead of apt-get.